# Как обязать использовать 32-битное обращение к структуре?

Tags: c++, x86-64

Есть некая структура с битовыми полями. Допустим

```
struct _example{ 
  unsigned f10:1;
  unsigned f11:1;
  unsigned f2:2;
  unsigned f4:4;
  unsigned f8:8;
  unsigned f16:16;
};
```

При обращении к f10 в виде а10|=1 формируется код `orb $1,(%rcx)`, а нужен `orl $1,(%rcx)`.
Регистр %rcx для примера, содержит адрес начала структуры.

Можно соответствующие переменные объявлять volatile, но это решение подходит для самого первого поля.

Если подумать, то компилятор не может определить границы 32-битных слов в структуре, поэтому обращается к байтам. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/17JQWM

Comment: А почему именно так? Думаете, будет быстрее?

Comment: Скажите название и версию компилятора. В идеале, сделайте пример на http://gcc.godbolt.org , который генерировал бы `orb $1,(%rcx)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat MMIO, адресация обязательна по 32-бита. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5S7lEc

Comment: Напишите что-то вроде `int set_enable() {
    volatile unsigned int *p = (__typeof__(p))&ex;
    
    return *p |= 1;
}` и компайлер вас услышит

Comment: @avp тогда проще использовать `unsigned int` вместо всей структуры и задавать битовыми масками значения. Только нужно будет описать кучу масок.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat между прочим, godbolt не совпадает в вырабатываемом коде. Я добавил volatile к описанию поля. Теперь код `orl`, но настоящий компилятор после этого делает `movb`, а не `movl`.

Comment: В смысле *"настоящий компилятор"* А на godbolt какой, поддельный? :) Скоре евсего, версия или настройки (или вообще название) отличаются.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тот код, что у меня получается идентичен коду версии 4.1.2 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-DkcMC Версия компилятора (gcc -v) 8.2. Попробую переустановить.

Comment: @Adokenai, какая у вас задача на самом деле, от этого и надо отталкиваться. volatile заставляет компилятор делать обращения к памяти при каждом доступе к переменной. Скорее всего (если вы не с аппаратурой напрямую работаете) это не совсем то, что вам нужно. И скорее всего для большинства  современных процессоров при обращении к RAM нет никакой разницы между доступом к байту и 32-bit слову.

Comment: @avp читайте внимательнее комментарии. MMIO - ввод/вывод отображаемый на память. И там эта разница существенна. Чтение и запись должна производиться только определёнными блоками. В моём случае (работа с HPET) нужен доступ 32-битными запросами.

Comment: @Adokenai, OK. Тогда не изобретайте велосипед и работайте как все люди через `volatile uint32_t *`. Надежнее всего (если не хотите каждый раз смотреть генерируемый asm) читать по такому указателю в локальную переменную (регистр), менять биты, а потом писать. Впрочем, раз программируете IO, то наверное сами все эти тонкости с последовательностью изменений регистров устройства  понимаете

Comment: @avp `volatile uint32_t []` Это разное. Я уже убедился.

Comment: @Adokenai, или я вашу проблему не понял, либо не смог объяснить. Обычно я пишу что-то в таком духе -- `volatile uint32_t *hdmi = (__typeof__(hdmi))SOC_HDMI_BASE; uint8_t revision = (uint8_t)hdmi[HDMI_REVISION_ID]; ...` Это в случае 8-бит device с адресами регистров, выравненными на 32 бит. А вы что именно имели в виду?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Это невозможно. Компилятор не может рассчитать 32-битные границы.

Comment: Как запасной вариант есть inline assembly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это не вариант. Потому что, получатся те же побитовые операции в коде как и в случае представления структуры в виде набора полей unsigned int, а не битовых полей. Даже ещё больше кода. У меня есть inline-функции с bts, но надеялся, что есть варианты лучше.